# recording a macro in excel for chart formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Does macro recording work for chart formatting?
I start recording a macro, create a chart in excel and apply a bunch of formatting on chart. Unfortunately, it is not recording VB code required for formatting. Is there a way to have it record formatting changes on a chart?

Comment: Providing the version of Excel will get you more helpful answers when asking a question :)

You could record your macro in 2003 and test it out in the other version to make sure it's compatible and runs successfully. The other option is writing a small VBA snippet of your own. I believe that's why VBA is highly supported compared to macro recording. 

Please take a look at this charting link as well:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692892.aspx

@brettdj I didnt have commenting ability earlier.

Comment: I suggest you look up how to code it manually. Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225645(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 2):

According to [Andy Pope](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76496&p=387734#post387734), "The charting engine is brand new in 2007 and the spitting out of VBA syntax did not make it in time." I assume this is the version you're using?

He suggests using an earlier version if possible, otherwise read up in the object browser, web search, or ask here for how to do the specific things you want to do. I think the ability to record chart formatting is in Excel 2010 too.

Line weight is set with `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).format.line.weight=2`

Line colour is set with `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Border.Color = RGB(255, 127, 0)`

Comment: You are correct. I get the marker setting to record, but not the line settings.

Comment: Did this answer your question or are there other things you're missing?

Comment: Yes this is doable. But the point of my doing this is to do things faster. I can search for specific things I want to do in API but it is a very dense API and sometimes it is easier to see the code in VB using a macro and replicate it in C#. It is cumbersome to ask questions for every little formatting help if I can't find it. Thanks